# Need explanation of how Stuff function and For XML Path works in this code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I inherited a SQL script from someone who left our company, and I'm not sure what it's doing.

The first part selects a username and their location and puts the data into a temp table #Roster:

```
    LastName  FirstName  Location
    Smith     John       Tampa Hospital
    Kennedy   Tom        Maine Hospital
    Smith     John       Orlando Hospital
```

The second part looks like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT lastname, firstname,
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + r1.location
from #Roster r2
where r1.lastname = r2.lastname
and r1.firstname = r2.firstname
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM #Roster as r1
```

When I look at the dataset from the Select that uses the STUFF function I don't see any difference from the first part of the code, except that the data is now ordered by name and location.

Can anyone tell why the second part of this script with STUFF and FOR XML PATH() is needed?

Thanks.

```
    LastName    FirstName    Location
    Kennedy     Tom          Maine Hospital
    Smith       John         Orlando Hospital
    Smith       John         Tampa Hospital
```

Comment: I read that thread but it doesn't explain the purpose of the code in my script.  The thread you're referring to shows the output as "aaa, bbb, ccc."  This isn't happening in my script.  I don't see why the STUFF function is being used here.

Comment: Because it is coded wrong. Using DISTINCT in the subquery prevents this from generating a comma separated list.

Comment: @SeanLange I think it's the fact that it says `r1.location` instead of `r2.location` not that it is using `distinct`. http://rextester.com/TRNL18297 -- But you are correct, it is coded wrong.

Comment: Removing DISTINCT from the subquery puts the location in a comma separated list, which would not be the desired output.  Changing r1.location to r2.location does the same thing.  So now I really can't tell the purpose of this part of the script.  I guess I could delete it in a test environment to see what happens.

Comment: @SqlZim yes it has a number of issues as posted.

Comment: Well if you don't want a delimited list, what do you want for output?

Comment: The desired output is to have one location per line, such as I showed in the tables above.  It seems like the STUFF function is irrelevant.   Like I said, I inherited this script and I'm trying to understand why it was coded this way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the DISTINCT is in this query not once but twice. The point of this type of query is to generate a delimited list of related values for a group. In your case it would be locations for each person. But the distinct and a couple other things have rendered this not working as expected.

Taking a guess here but I think your query should be something like this.

```
SELECT lastname
    , firstname
    , STUFF((SELECT ',' + location
    from #Roster r2
    where r1.lastname = r2.lastname
        and r1.firstname = r2.firstname
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM #Roster as r1
group by r1.lastname
    , r1.firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `r1.location` to `r2.location` location would provide the string concatenation you would expect.

I changed the aliases so as not to use numbers like the code in the question.

```
create table t (LastName varchar(32), FirstName varchar(32), Location varchar(32))
insert into t values 
 ('Smith','John','Tampa Hospital')
,('Kennedy','Tom','Maine Hospital')
,('Smith','John','Orlando Hospital')

select distinct lastname, firstname
, Location= stuff((select distinct ',' + i.location
    from t as i
    where t.lastname = i.lastname
      and t.firstname = i.firstname
    for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
from t
```

returns:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------------------------+
| lastname | firstname |            Location             |
+----------+-----------+---------------------------------+
| Kennedy  | Tom       | Maine Hospital                  |
| Smith    | John      | Orlando Hospital,Tampa Hospital |
+----------+-----------+---------------------------------+
```

but the code in the question references the outer table in the subquery for `location`:

```
select distinct lastname, firstname
, Location= stuff((select distinct ',' + t.location
    from t as i
    where t.lastname = i.lastname
      and t.firstname = i.firstname
    for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
from t
```

returns:

```
+----------+-----------+------------------+
| lastname | firstname |     Location     |
+----------+-----------+------------------+
| Kennedy  | Tom       | Maine Hospital   |
| Smith    | John      | Orlando Hospital |
| Smith    | John      | Tampa Hospital   |
+----------+-----------+------------------+
```